# Playing buffer in ObjectAL

Tags: ios, openal, objectal

I am new to ObjectAL. I use it to play mp3 with changed pitch.

I cannot figure out how to "properly" play a loaded buffer in ObjectAL. When I call `[source play:buffer]` the sound only comes a fraction of a second. To constantly "play" a buffer I can embed it in infinite loop and then the buffer is played correctly. I assume I miss some fundamental point, can you point me in the right direction?

My code:

```
[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance].reservedSources = 0;

ALSource *source = [ALSource source];

ALBuffer *buffer = [[OpenALManager sharedInstance] bufferFromFile:@"video.mp3" reduceToMono:YES];
source.pitch = 1;

for (;;) {   // infinite loop because otherwise only a millisecond of buffer is played
    [source play:buffer];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `pitchTo` or similar function actually makes the buffer play constantly, fx:

```
[source pitchTo:1 duration:1 target:nil selector:nil];
```

This does not qualify as a perfect explanation, however at least it solves the problem.